# MySQL 5.5 SELECT DISTINCT - How to return more than one column with no query duplicate?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, distinct

Seems like on MySQL 5.5 `SELECT DISTINCT` works fine just with one column.

```
SELECT DISTINCT type FROM table
WHERE type LIKE 'h%'
LIMIT 5;
```

returns good result:

```
type
--------
htm
html
htaccess
```

But on trying `SELECT` two or more columns

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, type FROM table
WHERE type LIKE 'h%'
LIMIT 5;
```

it returns failed result with duplicated queries:

```
id | type
---+--------
1  | htm
3  | htm
5  | html
6  | html
7  | html
```

Expected result:

```
id | type
---+--------
3  | htm
7  | html
5  | htaccess
```

Column `id` has no need to apply `DISTINCT`, since it has `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Comment: Well, the rows 1-htm and 3-htm are different, aren't they?

Answer (score 5):

You want a `group by`:

```
select
   max(id) as id,
   type
from
   table
where type like 'h%'
group by type
```

`distinct` gets you `distinct` rows--that means that unless *every* value in *every* column is the same as a row already in the result set, it'll show that row. In this case, it's behaving exactly as described.

By doing a `group by` and using aggregate functions (like `max`), you're specifying the columns that you want to be distinct, while you aggregate the other columns up to provide you the result set that you're looking for.

Comment: There are no need for `MAX( id ) AS id` or `MIN( id ) AS id`, it might be replaced with `id`. Your SQL with `LIMIT 5;` is 10 times slower then mine with `DISTINCT`. Any performance? Other way it works fine.

Comment: MySQL sucks at `group by`, sorry, but it does. You can use `distinct`, but it's not what you're looking for, and you're not grasping the difference between `distinct` and `group by`. Moreover, the selective `group by` without aggregates being displayed is only limited to MySQL--the syntax I gave is ANSI, and is the correct query to get what you want to do. My feeling is that your question is not well defined--what, exactly, is it that you're trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
  min(id) as id,
  type
FROM table
WHERE type LIKE 'h%'
GROUP BY type
LIMIT 5;
```

Answer (score 1):

They are not duplicated rows. Distinct means that each combination of column values is different for all others. As you can see, 1|htm  and  3|htm is not the same, then is different.

Comment: Not duplicated rows but **queries**.

Answer (score 0):

First, for clarification:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, type FROM table
WHERE type LIKE 'h%'
LIMIT 5;
```

This query works as expected, because id is an auto_increment, there are no dupes, so distinct is pointless.

Second, what are you trying to accomplish? Whether you do a DISTINCT or GROUP BY on the type column, you are going to get an ID which only represents one row in the table, even though several rows in the table share the same value (each with a different id).

Answer (score 0):

MySQL 5.5

SELECT DISTINCT - How to return one column with no query duplicate?

If you have an employee table like:

```
Eno Ename Location
```

When you have more than one location for an employee, and you want to see unique locations:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    Eno,Ename,(Location) 
FROM 
    Employee
```